# Jquery .on('click') function

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$('th').on('click', '.sorting > span', function() {
    alert("hello world");
});
```

This code used to work, but I have made a few changes to my site, and now it's not working. Here is an example of the code I am trying to apply the above function on:

```
<th style="text-align: center; width: 381px; " class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="devices" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Device: activate to sort column ascending"><span class="btn btn-mini" style="width: 100px">Device<span id="i"></span></span></th>
```

Here is an image of the button link and an Xray analysis:

[image]

EDIT: Ok, now some really insteresting stuff is happening!  When I wrap the above code in  `$(document).ready( function () {}` I finally see the alert when I click on the sorting column. However, when the sorting column is clicked on the th class changes to "sorting_asc"... but when I click on the button again, I still see the same alert... Obviously wrapping in document ready means jquery isn't aware of the updated DOM CSS. So, what might be causing the function outside of the document ready function to stop working?

Answer (score 3):

In your markup `th` element has no descendant element with class of `sorting` and your jQuery selector doesn't select any element, you should code:

```
$('th.sorting').on('click', 'span', function() {
    alert("hello world");
})
```

Comment: I tried that too. I don't know what else could be wrong... as I said the code used to work?

Comment: @Abram Your code only works when your `th` element has a  descendant element with class `sorting`.

Comment: Hey, I have multiple column header buttons.. using datatables.net jquery plugin.. so most of them are 'sorting'

Comment: @Abram What is the current issue?

Comment: Well, just that the code isn't working the way it did before.. I have no idea what has changed.. but obviously the code is correct, so I guess I've hit a stumbling block.

Comment: By the way, $('th.sorting_desc > span > #i').html(' <i class=\"icon-chevron-down\"></i>'); works on page load to add the initial sorting chevron to the column that is assigned to sort by default.

Comment: @Abram when you bind an event to an element, for unbinding that event you should use `off` method, otherwise the handler is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the selector ".sorting > span" when you really mean "span".  The ".sorting" part will not apply to the element you have selected first.

```
$('th.sorting').on('click', 'span', function() {
  alert("hello world");
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid I have 3 different th classes, so I need to be specific!